# dojo1.8: updating searchAttr of the ComboSelect from function

Tags: javascript, dojo

Hi I am trying to execute function from object creation. I am not sure if this is the right way.

I create select-combo box but because each database has different fields for batch, So I create a function to choose the correct 'batch and update searchAttr later so that the select can be populated.'

Please kindly advise.

```
function whichbatch(dbA)
    switch (dbA)
     {
    case 'testdata1970_05': 'batch';
    break;  
    case 'testdata1970_10': 'batch_no';
    break;
    case 'testdata2060_03': 'batch';
    break;
    case 'dbProdigy':'Batch';
    break;
    case 'dbProdigy_MK6N':'Batch'
    break;
}

var selBatch = new ComboBox 
(
    {id:'ID_selBatch',
    value:'',
    placeHolder:'Select...',
    style:{width:'200px'},
    },'node_selBatch'
);

on(selTest, 'change', function(valueCard)
{
    var selectedTest = this.get('displayedValue');
    var selBatch = registry.byId('ID_selBatch');
    selBatch.searchAttr:(whichbatch(registry.byId('ID_selPCBA').    
    console.debug('Connecting to gatherbatches.php ...');
    request.post('gatherbatches.php',
    {  data:{nameDB:registry.byId('ID_selPCBA').value, nameCard : valueCard},
            handleAs: "json"}).then
    (
function(response)
{
    var memoStore2 = new Memory({data:response});
    selBatch.set('store', memoStore2);
    selBatch.set('value','');
    console.debug('List of batches per Test is completed! Good OK! ');
},

function(error)
 {
    alert("Batch's Error:"+error);
    console.debug('Problem: Listing batches per Test in select Test is BAD!');
 });
selBatch.startup();
});
```

Comment: Hi I just realised that the better method is to rename the key in gatherbatches.php before encoding into json, instead of using the function. But how do I rename all keys to 'batch' regardless of the databases?

Comment: Turns out that I can add 'as' keyword when querying database!